# How to get a response from queue when passing correlationId? (System Design/RabbitMQ)

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, system-design

We want to use rabbitMQ as a broker for an email service.
For better UX, we want to firstly acknowledge to the client the request to send an email is processing, and then when it's completed - show him a verification.

From my understanding the practice to do so is to send a `correlationId` and when the job completes, send an approval message in a different queue with that `correlationId`.
The issue is - http requests are unidirectional. So how can I implement the response in this diagram?

[image]

Was thinking of:

1. WebSocket
2. WebHook/Pub-Sub that the client will be subscribed to

Are these valid? What are the practices in this situation?